# how to zero out all the registers in assembly without multiple instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, cpu-registers, micro-optimization

im trying to clear all the registers using this assembly code:

```
xor eax, eax
xor ebx, ebx
xor ecx, ecx
xor edx, edx
xor esi, esi
xor edi, edi
```

but is there any other effective way, like a single instruction or anything else

Comment: No, but there's not much reason to need to ever do this.

Comment: @RossRidge seems logical, i was just wondering if there is a single instruction that can clear all the regs, if you are sure about it kindly write it as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed ESP, out of the 8 general-purpose integer registers.

**No, there's no instruction to do this, and it would be bad design if Intel *had* included an instruction that only did that rare and obscure task.**  It would take transistors to decode and microcode to implement, and use up an opcode that could have been better used for some other instruction or future extension.something

There is [`fninit`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/finit:fninit) for the x87 stack registers which marks them as "empty" but doesn't actually zero the underlying regs.  And there's AVX [`vzeroall`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vzeroall) for the XMM/YMM0..15 vector registers (not YMM16..31 so with AVX512 it's not actually all).  That's a partner to `vzeroupper` which exists to avoid SSE/AVX transition penalties, otherwise they wouldn't have added it.

You'd want to do this once or twice in an OS kernel (e.g. for process startup before jumping to user-space, to avoid info leaks), and pretty much never in any other code.

You *could* `rep stosd` or `movdqa` some zeros onto the stack for `popa`, possibly in fewer instructions than 7x xor-zeroing instructions.  but worst code-size and certainly worse efficiency.  xor-zeroing is literally as cheap as a nop on modern Intel CPUs.

In a kernel, you'd probably already have a context-switch function, so you might take advantage of it by zeroing a context buffer and then calling the context-switch function to switch to it.

Comment: thank you that was helpful, i m accepting this answer.